# Can't get EF Code First to work in MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a new MVC 4 Internet Application in VS 2010. I created an "Item" model, and an "ItemContext" class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I built the project, then right clicked the "Controllers" folder, and attempted to add a new controller:

[image: Add Controller dialog box]

when I try to add it, I get the following error, which I do not understand:

[image: MVC Error]

I'm having bigger issues with this, but I thought I'd try boiling it down as simple as I could and see what I got. What steps am I missing? The "Internet Application" project has a connection string already, and it's got some membership related stuff as well.

**Update** This is the connection string the project creates:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Try changing the connection string name to `ItemContext`.

Comment: @Eranga well that did something, now `ColumnAttribute` is ambiguous, and there's another error that appears related to that. `ColumnAttribute` appears nowhere in the solution

Comment: There maybe `Column` attributes defined on a properties of a class. Are there any model classes apart from `Item`?

Comment: @Eranga That last one turned out to be a bug in MVC :\. The ambiguous reference was in the template files. Now I can create the controller, changing the connection string's name worked (although I figured it would default to DefaultConnection if I didn't create a new one)

Comment: ah. Didn't know about the bug.

Comment: You were right though, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the connection string name to `ItemContext`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way of doing it without need to rename connection. **DefaultConnection** may be any of yours connections.

```
public class ItemsContext : DbContext
{
    public ItemsContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

This approach gives you the benefit to avoid having new connection name for each new Model set.